# Problem about probability of throwing a dice to get different number

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

### My Question：

Roll a fair four-sided die, and let Y be the number of rolls needed to obtain all four different numbers.
Find P(Y = 5).

### My Attempt：

$$\frac{{4 \choose 3}{4 \choose 2}}{4^5}$$

${4 \choose 3}$ represents selecting three different numbers from the four numbers in the first four rolls.

${4 \choose 2}$ represents the arrangements of the three different numbers in the first four rolls, because two of the numbers will be repeated, so we divide by 2!

Is there anything wrong with my idea? Or are there any other methods?

Comment: Do you mean consecutive last 4 different roll results? If I roll, say 10 times, what does 'all four' mean in such a case?

Comment: This is a variation of the [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Comment: If you don't put that in a context of a probability distribution (e.g. an expectation value), the answer is anywhere between 4 and $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

I can't follow your calculation, specifically the $\binom 42$ part.

One method:

choose the duplicate tosses, $\binom 42$ ways to do that.

Choose the duplicate value, $4$ ways to do that.

Choose the value of the first singular toss, $3$ ways to do that.

Choose the value of the second singular toss, $2$ ways to do that.

Choose the value of the fifth, and final, toss.  Only $1$ way to do that.

Thus I see the answer as $$\frac {\binom 42\times 4!}{4^5}$$

which does not match your formula (though the two formulas have some similarities)

Should say, your answer seems far too small.  A hastily compiled simulator roughly matches my result.  Also:  The probability that you complete the cycle in $4$ tries is $$\frac {4!}{4^4}$$ which is considerably greater than your value.

Comment: Thank you! I found that I mix up the concept of permutation and combination.

Answer (score 0):

Another way: the problem with a direct approach is the risk of double counting, so we can try to use the inclusion-exclusion principle: Let $A_{i}$ be the event where the number $i$ always appears (in a sequence of length $5$). First, let's compute the probability of $A := \cap_{i \in [4]}A_{i}$:
$$
\mathbb{P}(A)= 1 - \mathbb{P}(\cup_{i \in [4]}A^{c}_{i}) = 1 - \dfrac{4*3^5 - 6*2^5 + 4}{4^5} = \dfrac{15}{64},
$$
where in the second equality, the inclusion-exclusion principle has been used. However, here we are including sequences where we see the $4$ numbers in the first 4 trials. There are 4!*4 such sequences, therefore our final answer is
$$
\dfrac{15}{64} - \dfrac{4!*4}{4^5} = \dfrac{9}{64}.
$$